# Why use scoped viewmodels when using dependency injection?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I was watching one of Philipp Lackners videos about Nested Navigation graphs and he brings up a helper function thats supposed to provide the same instance of the viewmodel to all the screens in the navGraph and to clear the viewmodel as soon as the navGraph is popped.

**This is the function:**

```
@Composable
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> NavBackStackEntry.sharedViewModel(navController: NavController): T {
    val navGraphRoute = destination.parent?.route ?: return viewModel()
    val parentEntry = remember(this) {
        navController.getBackStackEntry(navGraphRoute)
    }
    return viewModel(parentEntry)
}
```

He mentions the use of this function alongside hilt, but why would you need that? You will still have the same instance of the viewModel if you inject it in the screen anyway or am i missing something here?

Comment: "You will still have the same instance of the viewModel if you inject it in the screen anyway" - what do you mean by this? If you scoped a ViewModel to each screen, each screen would get its own instance, not the same one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually no, you will not have the same instance of the viewModel IF it's not scoped, hilt being able to construct a new view model instance without any trouble + any knowledge about a scope you want WILL create a new instance and inject it into the screen